# How to root and flash the Galaxy Note 4 AT&T version

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I got a Galaxy Note 4 from my father and it is the AT&T version. I think it's been already rooted since I can use other networks besides AT&T on it... But there are some AT&T stock apps/bloatware on it which I can't seem to get rid of. Is there a way to or is there a ROM I can flash on it? I heard there were no ROMS for this. And if there is a way to upgrade the PHONE from lollipop to marshmallow. Thank you.

DEVICE NAME: SAMSUNG-SM-N910A

Android version: 5.0.1

BASEBAND VERSION: N910AUCU2COC5

BUILD NUMBER  : LRX22C.N910AUCU2COC5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim unlock (being able to use different carriers) is not bootloader unlock or root. The SM-N910A cannot be rooted. You can root the T-Mobile version (SM-N910T). Your phone will update to Marshmallow baseband version N910AUCS2EQH1 when you check for updates with an AT&T sim card installed.